# is there any other method of getParcelableArrayListExtra?

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin

I did this code

```
val intent = Intent(context!!.activity, PreviewActivity::class.java) intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("images", arrayList as ArrayList<out Parcelable?>?) Log.e("click_prearrary", arrayList.toString()) intent.putExtra("position", position) intent.putExtra("statusdownload", true) intent.putExtra("isFrom", "downloaded") context!!.requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
    
    try { imageList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("images")!! viewPagerposition = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0) isFrom = intent.getStringExtra("isFrom").equals("downloaded") } catch (e: Exception) { e.printStackTrace()
```

Comment: 1. please format the code 2. what is wrong with this "method of getParcelableArrayListExtra"

Comment: Parcel android.os.Parcel@d6c1889: Unmarshalling unknown type code 244 at offset 168
I'am getting this error when i got the list in other activity

Comment: prolly it's a problem with whatever you have in `arrayList` ... again fix the code format and  provide type of `arrayList` if elemets are custom class implementing `Parcelable` provide implementation ... you need to learn how to ask the question ... remeber that we don't know how your code looks like

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- you can parse data using intent as follows as
https://medium.com/@hgarg701/parcelable-in-android-using-kotlin-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-c34801d7ff03

2- you can use Gson to send object or arrayList by using this method

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```

add in gradle

From Activity where you want to send ->

```
  val gson = Gson()
  val jsonUserInfoList = gson.toJson(userProfileInfoDetailedList)
                startActivity(Intent(
                    this@MainActivity,ProfileSettingActivity::class.java
                ).apply {
                    putExtra(Constants.USER_RRO_FILE_DETAIL,jsonUserInfoList)
               })
```

Activity where you want to get data ->

```
val userInfoDetailed = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_RRO_FILE_DETAIL)
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<UserProfileData>>() {}.type
    val userProfileList: List<UserProfileData> = gson.fromJson(userInfoDetailed, type)
```

3- if you want to communicate date between fragments you can follow as

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-viewmodel-in-android/

Comment: OP is already using point 1 from your "answer", but OP seems to have problem with implementation How this "answer" would help ? Also it is unclear what exactly is OP's problem

Comment: can you share code with me and what is OP???

Comment: you can use second part also

Comment: OP = original poster